# How to online view ,edit and attach signature to the document placed in windows azure storage

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a sample application where client A upload some sample document to windows azure storage , I want to build a user interface where client B views,edits and attaches a signature to the document and notifies the client A  , Is their any inbuilt document viewing editing tool provided by windows azure or should i write helper application to achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Windows Azure does not provide you with a document viewing/editing tool. I suggest you take a look at a commercial viewer/editor which supports Windows Azure (Blob Storage). Take Telerik's RadEditor for example:

[image]

- [Content Provider sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/dbfilebrowsercontentprovider/defaultcs.aspx)
- [Azure Content Provider for Telerik File Browser](http://azuretelerik.codeplex.com/releases/view/60657)

Note: This editor focuses on HTML, so you might want to check if it's easy to convert your document from/to HTML.

Comment: I want edit documents something like we do in google docs or office 365, can i integrate google docs feature?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution for your problem statement. You need to build a suitable application either Web based or Desktop based.

The task of viewing, editing, manipulating etc. will be done via accessing the APIs of Blob, for the notification and stuff, I suggest you use Azure Queue.

Implementation : When user-A edits Blob-A which has to be notified for user-B, have a queue for user-B and en-queue a message stating `USER-A edited Blob-A`. When user B logs in just read out all messages from user-B 's queue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am clear with notifying between two clients, how do i implement online document viewing and editing feature , I have built a web application that lists all the documents uploaded to azure storage, I want have edit feature something like google docs and office 365 provides